# More formatting in pie charts in Spreadsheet::WriteExcel (perl)

Tags: perl, excel

Does anyone know if it's possible to add more formatting to a pie chart? Such as, the showing the percentages of each slice on the graph itself or having the labels of each slice shown next/on it? Instead of only having one simple legend?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible with [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/) but it is possible with [Excel::Writer::XLSX](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX/Chart.pm).

Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

my $workbook  = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'chart_pie.xlsx' );
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();
my $bold      = $workbook->add_format( bold => 1 );

# Add the worksheet data that the charts will refer to.
my $headings = [ 'Category', 'Values' ];
my $data = [
    [ 'Apple', 'Cherry', 'Pecan' ],
    [ 60,       30,       10     ],
];

$worksheet->write( 'A1', $headings, $bold );
$worksheet->write( 'A2', $data );

# Create a new chart object. In this case an embedded chart.
my $chart = $workbook->add_chart( type => 'pie', embedded => 1 );

# Configure the series.
$chart->add_series(
    name        => 'Pie sales data',
    categories  => [ 'Sheet1', 1, 3, 0, 0 ],
    values      => [ 'Sheet1', 1, 3, 1, 1 ],
    data_labels => { value => 1 },
);

# Add a title.
$chart->set_title( name => 'Popular Pie Types' );

# Set an Excel chart style. Colors with white outline and shadow.
$chart->set_style( 10 );

# Insert the chart into the worksheet (with an offset).
$worksheet->insert_chart( 'C2', $chart, 25, 10 );

__END__
```

And this is the chart it that is displayed:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Just wondering, is there a way for Apple/Cherry/Pecan to appear as well? Also, I looked at Excel::Writer::XLSX, and the syntax seems similar, if not the same as Spreadsheet::WriteExcel. Is this true or am I not looking closely enough?

Comment: Also, is it possible to append to an excel file that has graphs in it?

Comment: 1. It is possible to add the names, values or categories to the data_labels. See the Chart.pm docs for more information. 2. The Excel::Writer::XLSX syntax is the same as Spreadsheet::WriteExcel. It is API compatible. There are currently some differences in functionality, see the docs. 3. It isn't possible to append to an existing excel file with this module.

Comment: (in cleanup) Can't locate object method "newdir" via package "File::Temp" at /home/gauravp/INSTALL/modules/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Excel/Writer/XLSX/Workbook.pm line 823.  -- I m getting this error.Any fix?

Comment: @virus It isn't good to append new questions to the end of a different question. Anyway, you probably need to update File::Temp.

Comment: due to some reasons I can't update File::Temp.I have fixed this by changing  823 line of Workbo‌​ok.pm as below
#my $tempdir = File::Temp->newdir( DIR => $self->{_tempdir} );
my $tempdir = File::Temp::tempdir(DIR => $self->{_tempdir});